# How to write 2d dynamic array to a file in C

Tags: c, arrays, fwrite

```
 int row,col,i,j;
 int **matrix;

 printf("Col:");
 scanf("%d",&col);
 printf("Row:");
 scanf("%d",&row);

 matrix= (int**) malloc(row* sizeof(int));
    if(NULL == matrix)
      {
      free(matrix);
      printf("Error.\n");
      exit(-1);
      }
for (i=0;i<row;i++)
{
  matrix[i] = (int*) malloc(col* sizeof(int));
    if(NULL == matrix[i])
      {
       free(matrix[i]);
       printf("Error.\n");
       exit(-1);
      }
}

for (i=0;i<col;i++)
   {
       for (j=0;j<row;j++)
     {
       matrix[i][j]=1+rand()%1000000;
     }
   }
FILE *tfile;


tfile=fopen("matrix.txt","w");
fwrite(matrix,sizeof(matrix),matrix,tfile);
fclose(tfile);
```

So my problem is whenever I try to execute this code output is being cryptic like this:
˜1œ °1œ È1œ à1œ a™w ¬Æ <
How do you write 2d array into a file if it is dynamic array? And what am I doing it wrong?

Comment: The code you posted doesn't compile. Please copy and paste the actual code that you ran.

Comment: no need to free matrix if it is NULL

Comment: I edited it so it must be working now. Sorry for the first time.

Comment: This is tangential to your main problem — Note that your cleanup code in the second allocation loop leaves all the prior rows still allocated, and the matrix as a whole.  Also, since you just failed to allocated `matrix[i]`, the call to `free(matrix[i])` is a no-op.  You need something more like `for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) free(matrix[j]); free(matrix);` — or, since you're about to exit anyway, you could decide to leave the memory allocated.

Answer (score 2):

This is wrong:

```
matrix= (int**) malloc(row* sizeof(int));
```

It should be `sizeof(int*)` instead of `sizeof(int)`.

This is wrong too:

```
for (i=0;i<col;i++)
   {
       for (j=0;j<row;j++)
     {
       matrix[i][j]=1+rand()%1000000;
```

When you allocated the arrays, you had `row` first and `col` second, but now you have `col` first and `row` second. It should be `matrix[j][i]` instead of `matrix[i][j]`.

And this is really, really wrong:

```
fwrite(matrix,sizeof(matrix),matrix,tfile);
```

Why would you think a pointer is a suitable value for `nmemb`? And pointers aren't arrays. You have a pointer, not an array, so you can't use a single call to `fwrite` to write out everything. You'll need to do this row-by-row from inside of a loop.

And even with your program working right, you'll still get "cryptic" output, since you'll be writing a bunch of random numbers in binary form. If you want them to be ASCII text, then you'll have to use something like `fprintf` instead of `fwrite`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to fix this line:

matrix= (int**) malloc(row* sizeof(int));

into this

matrix= (int**) malloc(row* sizeof(**int***));

**Edit**: as Joseph pointed, that is not the only problem in the code.

Comment: That's only one problem among many, and fixing just it won't fix the bad output.